# Change Video current time on Clicking P tag in React js

Tags: html, reactjs, video

I am trying to change the video's current time if I click on the P tag.

**Note: Each P tag will be able to change the current time to a different duration
e.g.**

**<p>Sample 1</p> // should change the current time to 10 seconds**

**<p>Sample 2</p> // should change the current time to 30 seconds**

Bellow is the code Currently I am trying to work on. Can anyone please let me know how can I change the current time clicking on the P tags.

```
const RecipeReview = () => {
return (
<div className='row'>
  <div className='col-sm-8'>
    <div className='row'>
      <div className='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9'>
        <video className='embed-responsive-item' controls>
          <source src={VideoLink} />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div className='col-sm-4'>
    <div className='row mt-2 ml-1'>
      <div className='w-100 mt-2 mr-2'>
        <div className='d-flex flex-nowrap align-items-center'>
          <p className='text flex-grow-1 mr-2'>
            Sample1
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className='d-flex flex-nowrap align-items-center'>
          <p className='text flex-grow-1 mr-2'>
            Sample2
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  );
 };
  export default RecipeReview;
```

Comment: Create a local state for the currentTime and update on click of `p` tags.

Comment: I have created a sample codebase - https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-ptolemy-qm33e?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Sarun I am trying to change the video current time. something like this "Video.currentTime=";